# How to solve the error " Could not determine command name from tag @command" with Drush?

Tags: drush

I'm installing drush v9 on the server as well as I try to port my command. I did several things but now get the error:

```
drush status

In BespokeDocBlockParser.php line 65:

  Could not determine command name from tag @command
```

I really have no idea where to look. I googled for the php file but could not even find it :-(

Any suggestion is appreciated.
...

I removed the drush.services.yml and rebuild the cache.
Drush status is now giving normal feedback so probably it is sometiming in the drush command.

My drupal.services.yml

```
services:
  tb.commands:
    class: \Drupal\tb\Commands\TbCommands
    tags:
      - { name: drush.command }
```

My generated php template

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tb\Commands;

use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;

/**
 * A Drush commandfile.
 *
 * In addition to this file, you need a drush.services.yml
 * in root of your module, and a composer.json file that provides the name
 * of the services file to use.
 *
 * See these files for an example of injecting Drupal services:
 *   - http://cgit.drupalcode.org/devel/tree/src/Commands/DevelCommands.php
 *   - http://cgit.drupalcode.org/devel/tree/drush.services.yml
 */
class TbCommands extends DrushCommands {

  /**
   * Start data collecting for the traderbot
   *
   * @param $para
   *   parameters in case i need this
   * @validate-module-enabled tb
   *
   * @command 
   * @aliases tb,traderbot
     */

    public function traderbot($para) {
      // See bottom of https://weitzman.github.io/blog/port-to-drush9 for details on what to change when porting a
      // legacy command.

    tb_log(3,'Start runnning traderbot from drush');



    tb_log(3,'End runnning traderbot from drush');

    }

}
```

The composer.json

```
{
    "name": "org/tb",
    "description": "This extension provides new commands for Drush.",
    "type": "drupal-drush",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author name",
            "email": "author@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "drush": {
            "services": {
                "drush.services.yml": "^9"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

function tb_log is part of the custom tb drupal module.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment on the `traderbot` method is incorrect:

```
   * @command 
   * @aliases tb,traderbot
```

There is no value after `@command`. I believe you want:

```
   * @command traderbot
   * @aliases tb
```

See: [Porting Commands to Drush 9](https://weitzman.github.io/blog/port-to-drush9)

Clear the cache after the change and try again.

Comment: Yes this is working. Very odd that drush 9 uses things in comment to have this working...

Comment: Drupal 8 etc makes a lot of usage of Annotations for definition and discovery. It’s new for 8.x devs but not necessarily a new paradigm.

Comment: Will dive into it.